# How to prove a unit norm matrix is the average of two unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove a unit norm matrix is the average of two unitary matrix

Comment: which norm is unit?

Comment: Do you know this is true? How many dimensions are you working in?

Comment: I think the only norm where this question makes sense is the spectral norm. I see the votes to close piling up, but since nobody has jumped in and said that this is a well-known elementary fact, I think if you add some details to your question, and flag it to be reopened, it probably will be. There's an easy proof for 2 dimensions and the spectral norm. My first reaction is that I wouldn't think it would be true for arbitrarily many dimensions, and the spectral norm, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Further to Peter Shor's comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: Moderators: Please rollback to the original statement of the question!

Comment: This is really weird. Where *IS* the original content? How is it not in the revision history?

Comment: I'm now convinced that this is indeed the original content, and that the question was entirely contained in the title. There's nothing to roll back to.

Comment: @Anton: Hehe. I see...

Answer (score 15):

I assume that the norm is the spectral norm.

By the polar decomposition, any unit norm matrix can be written as $UD$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is matrix which, in some basis $E$, is diagonal with non-negative entries not greater than $1$. The diagonal entries can thus be written as $\cos(\theta_1),...,\cos(\theta_n)$ for real $\theta_i$'s. $UD$ is then the average of $U V$ and $U V^*$ where $V$ is the matrix which, in the basis $E$, is diagonal with diagonal entries $e^{i\theta_1},...,e^{i\theta_n}$.

Comment: thanks for your answering this question. However I still doubt  whether the basis E is orthogonal(unitary) basis.

Comment: @yaoxiao: the matrix $D$ is hermitian (it is even positive semid-efinite), and every hermitian matrix can be diagonalized in an orthonormal basis. 

Comment: I see what you have mean，great！ I think it is really  interesting，
when we compare it with the similar claim “every matrix can be decompsed into linear combinations of  four orthogonal matrix